# What is the best way to change a variable in a php file from another php file

Tags: php, variables

What I am trying to do is change a variable in fileb from filea. Kind of like using fileb as a config file in a way.

Example:

**File A:**

```
require_once "fileb.php";

if($power == 'off') {
  exit;
}

if($test1 == 'one') {
  echo "The first option is selected";
} elseif($test1 == 'two') {
  $power = 'off';
}
```

**File B:**

```
$power = 'on';
```

So in this example a user id prompted for $test1, if they reply with "one" they get a echo. What I want to do is make it so if they reply with "two" it shuts down the page, and not just for them but for everyone. I am trying to do all of this without using a DB, that would be too easy lol. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can just use the `$_SESSION` associative array to transfer the value, that's cleaner than this mess, usually. DOn't gorget to call `session_start();`

Comment: @MightyPork `$_SESSION` would keep value for each user separately.

Comment: yes, i thought thats the purpose. Otherwise, well just use database.

Comment: I am avoiding databases in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to do all of this without using a DB, that would be too easy

There's a reason using a database for this is easy.  It's the correct way to accomplish this task.  Modifying *actual PHP code files* is a *famously bad idea*.  (And one that somebody on Stack Overflow has almost weekly, it seems.)

If you include the file as part of the executing code, you can use the variable as any other.  This allows you to manipulate the variable in a transient way, but not manipulate the code which creates the variable.

What you're trying to do is *persist* that changed variable.  In order to do that, it needs to be written somewhere outside of the application.  Databases are *really* good for that sort of thing.  You could also write to a simple text file (a string of text, structured XML, etc.) though in that case you'll have to manually watch out for concurrent writes and other such errors.  (Databases are really good at that too, which makes them ideally suited for multi-thread/multi-user applications like web apps.)

I suppose you *could* treat the PHP file itself as an editable text file like any other.  (Since PHP is, after all, just text.)  But, again, that's a really bad idea.  For one thing, parsing out exactly the value you want and writing back a change only to that value is going to be *very* difficult.  Also, you run the risk of breaking a file which is treated as *executable code* which opens up all sorts of potential risks.

Just write to a database, or to a file, or to any other simple data persistence medium outside of the application.

Comment: What would be the best way to write it to a file?

Comment: $file = 'fireworks/config.php';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current = '<?php $Test1 = disable; $Test3 = hahaha; ?>';
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);

Comment: Thanks, I got what I was looking for here what I ended up doing was: $current = '<?php $power = off; ?>';

Comment: @user2464339: Again, storing values *as PHP code* is a ***bad idea***.  It's been a bad idea every time somebody has it (which is surprisingly often), and it will continue to be a bad idea.  If you refuse to use a database for whatever reason, at least use some kind of serialized data file (XML, JSON, some structured format).  Data and code are two separate things.

Comment: Please help me to understand, what makes it a bad idea?

Comment: @user2464339: 1) Parsing PHP code is a lot more difficult and error prone than parsing structured data.  2) A broken write operation will result in broken production code, not just bad data.  3) Being code implies that you plan on *executing* this code at some point, which opens an avenue for security breach if users find a way to inject *specific* values into the file.  (Like SQL injection, but with PHP code.)  Honestly, why don't you want to store your data as, well, *data*?

Answer (score 1):

Your `fileb` is lacking the `<?php ... ?>` tags. Without those, you "code" is never seen as code. it'll just be treated as plain text.

file b:

```
<?php

$power = 'on';
```

file c:

```
Hello
<?php
$foo = 'world!';
```

file a:

```
<?php

include('fileb.php');

echo $power;

include ('filec.php'); // "Hello" is immediately output
echo $foo; // tell PHP to put the $foo var, which will print out "world!"
```

Comment: Looks like you forget `?>` in your examples :)

Comment: not necessary. end-of-file is an implicit `?>`. You'd only need it if you have some plaintext AFTER the code that you need to output.

Comment: I left out the <?php ... ?> tags in the examples however everything is in php in this example. I don't think I explained the problem well enough, I want to permanently change the variable in fileb from filea.

Comment: @user2464339: change the contents of the file, you mean? So rewrite the file and output legitimate PHP code into the file. otherwise if you're just changing the value, why include the file to start with? You could just have `$power = 'whatever';`

Comment: Or to be correct with SGML syntax. It can later cause troubles with parsing, concatenating sources etc.

Comment: wrap the php code in cdata blocks or whatever the sgml equivalent is. "hide" it. php won't care where it's in the file. you could embed a php code block inside a jpeg or a .exe if you so choose. php won't care. it'll just look for/execute anything inside `<?php ... ?>` blocks.

Comment: The objective is to have one action by one user be able to change everything for everyone. IE like an admin shutting something down.

Comment: PHP won't care, but SGML parser will care. I can't see any benefit from omiting ending `?>`, but I see many potential problems it may cause.

Comment: well yeah, if the PHP is embedded in something ELSE, then you need the `?>` to break out of PHP mode. but if the file is nothing but php, then it's redundant and actually a bad idea in some cases (e.g. `include()` a file with `?>whitespace whitespace` in another file that does session_start(), you'll have a bad time.)

Comment: `?>[whitespace]` is differend from `?>`, which is a good idea. And you never know if you won't need to embed PHP to something else or automatically concatenate sources. I don't see the point for getting into potential problems, which can be easily avoided with `?>`.

Comment: In normal practice I never leave a <?php tag open. Open tags are like open doors, they let bugs in.